# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList<Project> out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, arraylist, json-deserialization

I have this json

```
{
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 250,
  "size": 1,
  "_links": {
    "next": null,
    "prev": null
  },
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "test",
      "announcement": null,
      "show_announcement": false,
      "is_completed": false,
      "completed_on": null,
      "suite_mode": 1,
      "default_role_id": null,
      "url": "https://web.com/index.php?/projects/overview/1",
      "users": [],
      "groups": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "test2",
      "announcement": null,
      "show_announcement": false,
      "is_completed": false,
      "completed_on": null,
      "suite_mode": 1,
      "default_role_id": null,
      "url": "https://web.com/index.php?/projects/overview/1",
      "users": [],
      "groups": []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the **Project.java** model

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Project {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String announcement;
    private boolean is_completed;
    private String completed_on;
    private String url;
    private boolean show_announcement;
    private int suite_mode;
    private String default_role_id;

    public String getDefault_role_id() {
        return default_role_id;
    }

    public void setDefault_role_id(String default_role_id) {
        this.default_role_id = default_role_id;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAnnouncement() {
        return announcement;
    }

    public void setAnnouncement(String announcement) {
        this.announcement = announcement;
    }

    public boolean isIs_completed() {
        return is_completed;
    }

    public void setIs_completed(boolean is_completed) {
        this.is_completed = is_completed;
    }

    public String getCompleted_on() {
        return completed_on;
    }

    public void setCompleted_on(String completed_on) {
        this.completed_on = completed_on;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public boolean isShow_announcement() {
        return show_announcement;
    }

    public void setShow_announcement(boolean show_announcement) {

        this.show_announcement = show_announcement;
    }

    public int getSuite_mode() {
        return suite_mode;
    }

    public void setSuite_mode(int suite_mode) {
        this.suite_mode = suite_mode;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize from the given json only the "projects" to ArrayList
using this code.

```
String json = "{"offset":0,"limit":250}"; //for the example this is just part of the full json.
ObjectMapper mapper =  JsonUtils.getObjectMapper();
JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(json);
TypeReference<ArrayList<Project>> typeReference = new TypeReference<ArrayList<Project>>() {};
ArrayList<Project> projectList = mapper.reader().readValue(parser,typeReference);
```

tried also this line:

```
ArrayList<Project> projectList = mapper.reader().forType(typeReference).readValue(json);
```

and getting this exception for both:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<Project>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

anyone can help me with this?
My goal is to extract only the projects from the root level, without using JsonNode.get("projects")

Comment: The structure you want to deserialize is placed in an object. So you must also define a class containing a property _private List<Project> projects;_  and deserialize to an object of that class.